# Django: can't load static files from template on DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: django, nginx, django-templates, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

I'm having issues loading static files from a template in my Django app running on DigitalOcean machine.

Here is my Nginx configuration file (etc/nginx/sites-available/django):

```
# your Django project's static files - amend as required
location /static {
    alias /home/workspace/app-toscana/django/djangoapptoscana/djangoapptoscana/static;
}
```

Here it is my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH, )
```

Here is an example of template file call:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I tried different solutions, especially changing settings.py file, without any result.
Maybe there is any king of problem in the Nginx and gunicorn configurations that I'm not able to find.

Comment: Try and work out what part of your configuration the error is in. Are the links created in the template files as you expect? Put a file in `/home/workspace/app-toscana/django/djangoapptoscana/djangoapptoscana/static` (if there aren't any already, and try to access it at `/static/myfile.txt`. Check what the Nginx logs say. Re-read the [static files deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#deployment). In particular, you don't seem to have set `STATIC_ROOT` or run `collectstatic`. Good luck figuring out the problem :)

Comment: The STATIC_ROOT is set. Running manually the server with the command `python manage.py runserver localhost:9000` I can't see any particular issue on the server shell, but if I try to reach the page using the public IP server address I can't load the static file receiving a 404 error (on the static file). E.g. `GET http://188.166.72.87/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css => STATUS 404`

Comment: I've execute the `collecstatic` command too without any result.

Comment: `runserver` and nginx are too very different things. How is `STATIC_ROOT` defined, there is no such code in your question. Also, try to remove `STATICFILES_DIRS` from your live settings to see how it goes, then I will explain.

Comment: Here it is my static files configuration (from settings.py)
`STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/workspace/app-toscana/django/djangoapptoscana/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/' ` There are no `STATIC_PATH` and `STATIC_DIR` variables.

Comment: I posted a complete log issue on DigitalOcean Ask form. It can be found at the following [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/django-can-t-load-static-files-from-template-using-ubuntu-14-04-django-droplet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I found a solution to this problem. It was a permission issue. On my DigitalOcean machine I set the owner of the django app directory to root:root

`chown -R root:root /home/django/djangoapptoscana/dashboard`

and the owner of the static files directory to django:django

`chown -R django:django /home/django/djangoapptoscana/djangoapptoscana/static`